# Split each word present in different tags of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, popup

at this link I have posted a similar question but now I have to improve the function I want. 
 Please read to understand: [How to split each word in <p> (html) considering other elements inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913199/how-to-split-each-word-in-p-html-considering-other-elements-inside). 
 
The first solution of a user is great and works well if I consider only `<p>` tags, but now I have to consider all the following tags that could be in a webpage: 
 `span, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, em, strong, q, abbr, acronym, address, li, dd, dt, a, td, th, caption, legend, label, option`. 
 
I have always to split each single word inside the tag and put a `<span>` tag around it (es: `<h2> ...<span> word </span>...</h2>`, but now there is a complication: 
 
some tags could be alone or inside of other tags (for example tag `<a>` could be outside or inside a `<p>` tag, and a lot of other tags of the list above with the same use). In this way the solution proposed is not optimal because insert two different `<span>` tag around the same word, one due to `<p>` and one due to `<a>` when the code run. 
 I explain it with a more complex example and different tag elements:

Invented part of html page :

```
<a> Text of lorem ipum </a>
<h2> Lorem <span>ipsum</span> dolor <em>sit</em> amet, <a>consectetur</a> adipiscing <strong>elit</strong> </h2>
```

The solution proposed does:

tag without anyone inside, works correct

```
<a>                            
   <span>Text<span>    
   <span>of<span>
   <span>lorem<span>
   <span>ipum<span>
</a>
```

tag with someone inside, works bad

```
<h2>                                       
   <span><span><span> Lorem </span></span></span>        //3times
   <span(original)><span><span><span> ipsum </span></span></span></span(original)>  //3times + original one
   <span><span><span> dolor </span></span></span>               //3times
   <em><span><span><span> sit </span></span></span></em>        //3times
   <span><span><span> amet </span></span></span>                //3times
   <a><span><span><span><span> consectetur </span></span></span></span></a>     //4times
   <span><span><span>adipiscing</span></span></span>                //3times
   <strong><span><span><span>elit</span></span></span></strong>      //3times
</h2>
```

It works recursively so it creates different  for the different tags it meets,
but the result I want to achieve is:

```
<a>                            
   <span>Text<span>    
   <span>of<span>
   <span>lorem<span>
   <span>ipum<span>
</a>

<h2> 
   <span>Lorem</span>       
   <span(original)><span>ipsum</span></span(original)> 
   <span>dolor</span>              
   <em><span>sit</span></em>      
   <span>amet</span>               
   <a><span>consectetur</span></a>    
   <span>adipiscing</span>             
   <strong><span>elit</span></strong>  
</h2>
```

I don't know how to edit the code below to avoid the copy of `<span>` during the recursion or in the case it already exists.

Code of the solution used until now (to improve):

```
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'foo';
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));

for (const p of document.getElementsByTagName('p')) { //I've tried to change in document.querySelectorAll('p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,em,strong,q,abbr,acronym,address,li,dd,dt,a,td,th,caption,legend,label,option') 
    const walker = document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
    const textNodes = [];
    for (let n; (n = walker.nextNode());) {
        if (n.nodeValue.trim()) {
            textNodes.push(n);
        }
    }
    for (const n of textNodes) {
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (const s of n.nodeValue.split(/(\s+)/)) {
            if (s.trim()) {
                span.firstChild.nodeValue = s;
                fragment.appendChild(span.cloneNode(true));
            } else {
                fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
            }
        }
        n.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, n);
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can get outer element's (I used `outerElement` to make the snippet work but you can use the tag you want) `innerHTML` and split it by words. Then by using `Array.map()`, you can wrap them with `<span>` tags.

```js
const documentChildren = document.getElementById('outerElement').children;

for (let node of documentChildren) {

  node.innerHTML = node.innerText.match(/\S+/g).map(text => `<span>${text}</span>`).join('');

}
```

```css
span{
  display: block; // only to show spans separate
}
```

```html
<div id="outerElement">
  <a> Text of lorem ipum </a>
  <h2>
    Lorem
    <span>ipsum</span> dolor <em>sit</em> amet, <a>consectetur</a> adipiscing <strong>elit</strong> </h2>
</div>
```

I hope I understand your question and this helps you.